# Wordpress вывод контента

Tags: content, php, wordpress

В общем, в чем вопрос: мне надо, чтобы на странице выводился результат работы php-скрипта, там выводится данные в xml вида `<?xml...?> <xml><offer></offer>...<offer></offer></xml>`.

Я сделал отдельный шаблон:

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

И скрипт записал в контент, но он результат работы скрипта, каждый тег `<xml>` и `<offer>` оборачивает в `<p></p>`.

Как либо убрать эти `<p>`, либо по-другому получить результат работы скрипта?

Comment: @Bo6JI9, вышеописанное - результат работы фильтров при выводе контента в `the_content()`. Можно либо дерегистрировать фильтр (точно не подскажу как, но есть в документации), либо вообще выводить напрямую:

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        global $post;
        echo $post->post_content;
    endwhile; ?>

Comment: в таком случае он выводит просто текст php-скрипта, а не результат его работы, буду искать, чтобы деригистрировать(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Bo6JI9](/users/17034/bo6ji9)](/users/17034/bo6ji9), как и сказал [[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki), вам поможет удаление фильтра.
Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```

Подробнее об этой функции можно почитать тут: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop